# Where can I find the file format definition for a ZXING "Send History" ~.csv file entry?

Tags: zxing

I scanned several items using ZXING, after which I emailed the scan history as an attached ~.csv file. I can't find the definition of the fields in the scan history ~.csv file record, though four of them are easy enough to figure out.

1. Scanned barcode;
2. Second copy of scanned barcode;
3. Barcode format;
4. Unknown; (sometimes used as file name);
5. Timestamp; and
6. Unknown. (Record delimiter?).

Were can I find what the 4th and 6th fields are, and how they are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the source code, at least: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/history/HistoryManager.java#L266

(... which I've just realized doesn't mention the 6th field, oops. Will fix that doc.)

- Raw text of the barcode
- Display text (which is often the same)
- Format name
- Timestamp (standard Unix timestamp / ms from the epoch)
- Formatted timestamp
- Any info retrieved for the scan, like price info for a product barcode

Comment: I had the advantage that I sent the ~.csv file to myself, so I knew the identity of the application that generated the file. Someone receiving the history file who did not generate the data themself would not necessarily know where to look to find the format definition. May I suggest that the identity of the fields in the history should shown as column titles in the ~.csv file, at least those generated by the stand-alone applicaton, and the identity of the generating software should be listed as a final record in the csv file?

Comment: Fair enough. I hate having to strip headers and at this point dont wish to change the format that is expected. I also thought it was sort of clear what the values are but not entirely.